# What to do when a DLL needs a bigger stack size than the main exe application?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, stack, stack-size

I have a simulation engine written in Visual C++ 2010 and I'm implementing a DLL plugin based on it for another 3rd party application.

However, I get a stack overflow error when my library is called by the 3rd party app's thread. After debugging it turned out that the DLL requires a bigger stack size than the thread has. Is it possible to extend the current thread's stack size somehow?

I know I should probably review the simulation engine's code and move big objects to the heap. The problem is that the engine is maintained by another vendor and I'd like to avoid modifying their code if possible.

I'm thinking about creating my own thread in the DLL with a bigger stack size and returning the results to the calling thread when the calculation finishes. Is it the right approach?

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: "It seems that my DLL requires a bigger stack size than the thread has."  Have you debugged this?  Does the thread have an unusually small stack size?  The default stack size (1 MB) is quite generous.  If you're overflowing that, I would check for runaway recursion or large buffers declared at function scope.  If you do have large buffers on the stack, try moving them to the heap.  Creating your own thread is a way to get a larger stack, but be aware that you might just be hiding a real bug or design flaw.

Comment: I edited the answer - yes, I debugged that. It has the default stack size, but the code allocates big buffers and data structures on the stack and requires about 10mb of stack. Right, I can move the stuff to the heap, but I'd like to know the alternatives since I'd like to avoid modifying the heart of the simulation model just because the 3rd party app has a small stack size.

Comment: Right. But I'm integrating another vendor's code and I'd like to avoid modifying it.

Comment: There are situations where there is no control over stack usage and only a modest increase in allocation is needed to make things work. I got here writing a plugin wrapper that glues a dll I don't control to an outer application with default sized stack allocation.  I can fix my personal copy of the executable with editbin but I don't know how I can apply that solution to the users of my plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I had your exact same problem and solved it by spawning a thread with a larger stack size. My code that needs the large stack is well-isolated set-up code, so it was a fairly simple solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that the *first* thing you check is how much stack space you're actually using. Are you allocating large objects on the stack? Does your program utilize significant recursion depths? Write a test hook application you can link into your DLL and check how much stack space you use.

If you're allocating large objects on the stack I would strongly suggest moving them to the heap.

If you're doing significant recursion you may wish to investigate using a loop with a heap-based stack maintained by your DLL rather than relying on the application's stack.

I make these suggestions simply because it's much less intrusive for a plugin to be self-contained and not require special stack configuration (or even an entirely separaate thread just to have a larger stack).

Comment: I have access to the source code of the simulation engine, but it's "owned" by another vendor and I was wondering if I could do something without modifying their code.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio gives you two options to change default stack size (1MB):

/F for compiler:
https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size

/STACK for linker:
https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/stack

Answer (score -1):

You can [check and increase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67236352/12385909) reserved stack size of the main executable. Just open the Command Prompt for VS (I have VS 2019 installed and it is called "*Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019*"), navigate to the main application's folder and type:

```
editbin /stack:N main.exe
```

where N - stack size in bytes (e.g. if you want 4MB type 4194304).

Worked for me.

Comment: Technically this can work, but it is the anti-pattern known as "global solution to local problem".  What happens when plugin A needs a large stack and plugin B needs a huge number of threads?  It's clearly better for plugin A to override the stack size for a single thread of its own creation than tamper with all threads in the whole process.  Also note that `editbin` will invalidate code signing.