# How to know the stack size limit of .exe program?

Tags: gcc, stack, mingw, exe, stack-size

It seems my program (built with mingw `g++`) crashes due to insufficient stack memory. I use the compiling option `-Wl,--stack,64000000` to increase the stack limit but the problem persists. I want to know if there is a utility or method to check the current stack limit of my `.exe` program, so I can verify the limit is indeed changed to that value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There must be a way to examine PE executables (I am not familiar with the Windows environment). For ELF, the proper tools would be `readelf`, `nm`, `objdump` and suchlike (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542041/what-is-c-c-data-segment-and-stack-size). Also, be aware that you might be hitting some other stack limit constraint, because it is not the property of an executable but rather of the environment (OS, shell,...). On a unix system using `bash`, one can call `ulimit -s` to get current stack size limits. Lastly, are you using a GNU linker?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744650/how-to-overcome-stack-size-issue-with-visual-studio-running-c-codes-with-big-ar), to check the stack size you need to install Visual Studio and use the visual studio tool `dumpbin`. Usually there is a script that can be run to bring a command prompt windows with all the visual studio tools in path, this is vcvarsall.bat or "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" (or something like that) from the start menu.

Run

```
dumpbin /headers executable.exe
```

This will return a long output. In that output, look for `OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES` and in that part, there will be a `size of stack reserve` . The default stacksize is written as `100000` (hex) i.e. 1 Megabytes.

You can change the stacksize of an executable by using `editbin`, also provided by Visual Studio:

```
editbin /stack:N executable.exe
```

Here N is the number in bytes (in *decimal*) for the stacksize.